# PHP function inside single quotes display is as text

Tags: php, function, get

I have a function that display the list of users which is `displayUsers()`.

Basically instead of having 1 different php file for each page, I have used a switch function to load the content like. This is an example of 1 of the pages.

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {

   case '#userlist' : $page = '
       <div class="innerbox">
            displayUsers();
       </div> '; break;
}
```

As you can see it is supposed to show the `div` tag and load the function, however instead of loading the function, is just displaying the text "displayUsers()". I understand why it is doing this however I'm not sure how to change it so that is actually runs the function rather that displaying it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`displayUsers()` is inside quotes. It's interpreted as a string. You want

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {

   case '#userlist': $page = '<div class="innerbox">' . displayUsers() . '</div>'; break;

}
```

This concatenates the return value of displayUsers() inside the string, assuming displayUsers() returns the code.
I think you were confusing [this feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) where **variables inside double quoted strings are parsed. This does not work for functions.**

You could also use `case '#userlist': $page = sprintf('<div class="innerbox">%s</div>', displayUsers(); break;`

Read about sprintf here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

---

If `displayUsers()` actually outputs the code itself, then you can use

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {

   case '#userlist': echo '<div class="innerbox">'; displayUsers(); echo '</div>'; break;

}
```

What happens is the opening tag is printed, then the function is called (printing the code), then the closing tag is printed, in that order.

---

If you're getting `function not defined()` then it's exactly what it sounds like. The function has not been defined in the current script.

**How PHP works**
Each time a page is requested (someone goes to "foo.php"), your server and PHP engine gets the file (foo.php) from some directory, parses it, and (usually) sends something back to the user in the form of an HTML document. Each page is like a "script", kind of like a mini application that is compiled, executed once, and **forgotten**.

So let's say on your homepage you have `displayUsers()` defined.

```
//index.php

function displayUsers() {
    //some code...
}

echo "Welcome to my website!", "<br />", 'Click <a href="foo.php">Here</a>.';
```

When someone goes to your homepage, `displayUsers()` is defined, yay! However, it's forgotten right afterwards - the PHP engine has discarded the script after it's loaded and finished, and certainly does not know what `displayUsers()` is by the time you reach `foo.php`.

---

**So what can you do?**
If you're only using the function on one page, declare it on that page. Remember, each file is thought of as a script. The PHP engine doesn't keep track of functions over the user's session.

If you're using the function in multiple scripts, include your functions in some "central" file and [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it wherever you need it. I really suggest you read more into PHP and `include`; I'm not going to explain the basics of PHP; you need to do some more homework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the . (dot) to append strings when using singleqotes:

```
$page = '<div class="innerbox">'.displayUsers().'</div>';
```

Comment: I have tried this but it then produces an error saying that the function is undefined. There is a PHP file on the main page that I have included which defines the function, however do I have to include that in the page with all the `cases` ?

Comment: Do you include the PHP file with the cases into the main page? If no, you need to do so or call the function from the PHP file where you have the cases, another thing: is your querystring realy "#userlist"?

Comment: yes I have includes the PHP file with all the `cases` and also includes the file that defines the function.

Comment: Than it SHOULD work correctly. Or you include this page first and than the one with the function?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
case '#userlist' : $page = '
           <div class="innerbox">'
                .displayUsers().
           '</div> '; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the concatenation `.` operator this way:

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {

   case '#userlist':
       $page = '
       <div class="innerbox">'
       . displayUsers() .
       '</div> ';
       break;
}
```