# textarea not submitting into database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, textarea, nicedit

I have a form im trying to submit, into my MySQL database and its submitting all the records fine accept the 'content' field in my blog table.

Im not sure if this matters but i am using a textarea framework from nicedit.com

UPDATE: I have removed the NicEdit framework and it worked fine submitting as a normal textarea, im not really sure where to go with this now i'll try and take my support over to NicEdit and post a response when i have found a solution to this issue.

HOWEVER i am having another issue and would hate to open a new post about it, my date is inserting as 0000-00-00 and not the current date. Any solution to that?

heres the php post method

```
<?php
include_once"dbconnection.php";
session_start();
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die (@mysql_error());
$selectdb = mysql_select_db($database, $connect) or die (@mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['postblog'])){
    $blogtitle = $_POST['blogtitle'];
    $blogcontent = $_POST['blogcontent'];
    $author = 'Admin';
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog SET date='date()', title='$blogtitle', author='$author', published='1', content='$blogcontent'");
    if ($query == false){
        echo "false";
    } else {
        echo "true";
    }
}
?>
```

and the html form

```
<form action='postblog.php' method='post'>
    <input class="inputMed" type="text" name="blogtitle"> <br />
    <textarea style="width: 600px;" name="blogcontent"></textarea> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="postblog" id="postblog" value="Post Blog" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I smell SQL injection. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Just a guess, you have un-escaped characters in your 'blog content' that MySQL does not like. Try sanitizing your content before insertion.

Comment: any mysql errors? it looks fine to me. what Vaibhav said is most likely though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks i'll keep that in mind, for now i want to get my functionally down, i'll worry about security later. Or do you think im going at it the wrong way?

Comment: @VaibhavDesai i changed it from a textarea to input and it worked just fine... so it must be an issue within the framework is what your saying?

Comment: You're setting yourself up for failure if you don't worry about MySQL security as you're writing code.  I suggest you read up on prepared statements, they're lifesavers when it comes to preventing SQL Injections.

Comment: @AaronRussell It's almost definitely in the NicEdit framework.  See the answer I provide below.

Comment: For the date problem, get rid of the quotes around `date()`. They're preventing it from running the function.

Comment: After reading @ThiefMaster articles posted ive decided to go with MySQLi and i am VERY thankful for that information provided by him. If i wouldnt have known that information i would have really been stuck re coding a lot of things in the future

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your editor is submitting to a different variable (or not submitting it at all). One way to tell would be to have your PHP do something like this:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Put that in your script temporarily to see what gets submitted and by what name. If you see it, great. If you don't see your content you will know that the problem isn't PHP related and you will have to look into the nicedit side of things.

Comment: Wow awesome, this will serve me well for a lot of further debugging tasks. Thanks

Comment: So correct me if im wrong, but basically i place this where i would put the 

      } else {
           echo "true";
      }

Comment: I recommend putting it at the beginning of the file, right after "<?php". It doesn't really matter where you put it as long as it runs, it will print out all your input variables.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your `HOWEVER` date issue. Your `'date()'` is being parsed as a string not a function, and you have not defined your parameters. Change to-

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog SET date='".date('Y-m-d')."', title='$blogtitle', author='$author', published='1', content='$blogcontent'");
```

Or using MySQL [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)-

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog SET date=NOW(), title='$blogtitle', author='$author', published='1', content='$blogcontent'");
```

Or using MySQL [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)-

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog SET date=CURDATE(), title='$blogtitle', author='$author', published='1', content='$blogcontent'");
```

see also - [PHP function inside single quotes display is as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437975/php-function-inside-single-quotes-display-is-as-text)

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [NicEdit data not in POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481032/nicedit-data-not-in-post), you will need something like this:

```
<INPUT type=submit name="submit" value="Send" onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('blogContent').saveContent();">
```

And possibly something along the lines of this:

```
var editor = new nicEditors.findEditor('blogContent');
var content = editor.getContent();
```

That should point you in the right direction.  If you want a specific answer, you will need to specifically direct your question to someone who knows and/or uses NicEdit, because your issue is specifically related to how it (NicEdit) is wrapping your DOM in a non-standard way.

Comment: where in his post does it say he's using NiceEdit?

Comment: In the part where he says "Im not sure if this matters but i am using a textarea framework from nicedit.com."  Please don't down-vote answers until you have read about that upon which you are commenting.

Comment: If the docs [here](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API) say what they appear to be saying, adding the `onClick` event method above to your submit button should work, as should adding that method to a form `onSubmit` event

Comment: Hey @ChrisOstmo thanks for your answer! I didnt your answer before updating my post. But your right, i'll give that a try and see where it takes me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For The date problem you can use mysql currdate function like

```
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog SET date='DATE: Auto CURDATE()', title='$blogtitle', author='$author', published='1', content='$blogcontent'");
```

And for Nicedit Try This

```
   try this code
   <html>
   <head>
    <script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
   </head>

   <body>
    <form action='postblog.php' method='post'>
     <input class="inputMed" type="text" name="blogtitle"> <br />
     <textarea style="width: 600px;" name="blogcontent"></textarea> <br />
     <input type="submit" name="postblog" id="postblog" value="Post Blog" />
   </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: And for the NicEdit are you using multiple text area in the html?
Please post the entire html code as i have used nicEdit many Times and it works fine.

Comment: My coding has changed a lot as i switched to MySQLi and am using prepared statements, i would rather open another topic on it. I have found more useful information regarding this issue, im appending all my divs that display the different forms. And have tried many different textarea plugins now. And none are working, so im certain its the fact that im appending my divs and its just not recognizing because one thing i noticed to is that in all of the plugins i've used, none of them let me actually click any of the buttons. Will post link ASAP